# Displaying numpy arrays with matplotlib inside wx

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, wxwidgets

I have a huge numpy ndarray with shape (M x N x 3) and datatype `float32`.  I want the image to simply display in a `wx.Frame` that has a `wx.ScrolledWindow` attached.  I want the image at 100% zoom and it is VERY important that no data loss occurs.  These are super hi-res x-ray images that NEED to stay as floating point values.

So far the `wx.Image` capabilities have failed as they will only accept ndarrays with 8 bit integers.  no good.

The PIL imaging library can only handle 8 bits as well, not enough.

So far the only library I have found to be sufficient is matplotlib, but I'm having trouble getting matplotlib to display the way I want it to.  This gets me close:

```
class View(wx.Frame):  
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,  
                          parent=None,  
                          title="DICOM Viewer",  
                          size=(1280, 750),  
                          pos=(0,0))  
        self.scroll = wx.ScrolledWindow(self, -1)
        self.figure = plt.Figure()  
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasWxAgg(self.scroll, -1, self.figure)  
        self.axes = Axes(self.figure, [0,1,0,1])       
        self.figure.figimage(ndarray)     
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.EXPAND)  
        self.scroll.SetSizer(self.sizer)
```

The figimage function will display nothing but the raw pixels, which is what I want, but it only fills in the viewable area of the wxFrame and is super slow.  Maybe its a problem with my wx widgets?

A better solution was to use the imshow as such:

```
class View(wx.Frame):  
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,  
                          parent=None,  
                          title="DICOM Viewer",  
                          size=(1280, 750),  
                          pos=(0,0))  
        self.scroll = wx.ScrolledWindow(self, -1)  
        self.figure = plt.Figure()  
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasWxAgg(self.scroll, -1, self.figure)  
        self.axes = Axes(self.figure, [0,1,0,1])  
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)  
        self.axes.imshow(ndarray)  
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.EXPAND)    
        self.scroll.SetSizer(self.sizer)
```

However, this gives me a lot of padding around the plot, unnecessary axes and labels, and it auto-scales the image to fit inside the viewable area.  The pixel quality is still there but requires adding the mpl toolbar and manually panning around and you can loose track of the image if you pan too far.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

> ```
> class View(wx.Frame):  
>    def __init__(self):
>      wx.Frame.__init__(self,  
>                       parent=None,  
>                       title="DICOM Viewer",  
>                       size=(1280, 750),  
>                       pos=(0,0))  
>      self.scroll = wx.ScrolledWindow(self, -1)
>      h, w, r = ndarray.shape
>      self.figure = plt.Figure((w/72.0,h/72.0), 72)  #manually determine the figure size in inches
>      self.canvas = FigureCanvasWxAgg(self.scroll, -1, self.figure)  
>      self.axes = self.figure.add_axes([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]) #size of axes to match size of figure
>      self.axes.imshow(ndarray)
> ```

So the key was to manually set the size of the figure to be the full size of the image in inches and then set the axes for the figure to the same size.  This prevented mpl from automatically resizing my image to the viewable area. I also dropped the sizer because I manually sized the scrollbar's virtual area, the figure, and axes.  Now if only I could get rid of the figure's padding at the top I'd be all set.